# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at line 34

Tags: oracle, plsql

for this particular block, i am continuously getting

> ora 0142 : exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

, i have tried distinct, rank and rownum, but nothing seems to work.

```
begin 
  for i in c1 loop
    if i.estacao_a2 is not null then
      begin
        select migrationidentifier
          into v_master_location
          from (
                    select com.migrationidentifier
                         , row_number () over (partition by com.migrationidentifier order by com.migrationidentifier asc) RK
                      from com_location com
                     where round (i.latitude_a_decimal, 1) =
                            round (com.LATITUDEWGS84, 1)
                       and round (i.longitude_a_decimal, 1) =
                            round (com.longitudewgs84, 1)
                       and com.sourcedomain = 'FENIX'
               )
         where rk=1
             ;
      exception
        when no_data_found
          then dbms_output.put_line ( 'NO RECORDS FOUND IN COM_LOCATION FOR LATITUDE:' || i.latitude_a_decimal);
      end;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Where have you placed the `distinct` keyword ?

Comment: This just means that you have more than one migrationidentifier values for that set of latitude_a_decimal and longitude_a_decimal values used in the where clauses.

Comment: hi collapser , i had used the below mentioned query before but getting the same error                                                                                     select distinct com.migrationidentifier
           into v_master_location
           from com_location com
          where round (i.latitude_a_decimal, 1) =
                   round (com.latitudewgs84, 1)
                and round (i.longitude_a_decimal, 1) =
                       round (com.longitudewgs84, 1)
                and com.sourcedomain = 'FENIX';

Comment: Hi Michael            If i run the query, i am getting the desired results. the same is not working in the script which i am running here.

Comment: there must be a combination of values somewhere in that loop that is raising the error.  catch the too_many_rows exception and output the values to see what they are.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have more than one migrationidentifier in com_location for that set of latitude_a_decimal and longitude_a_decimal. Is this bad data? Or possible? Or there is some ordering criteria that will determine which one are you supposed to take?

If there is an ordering criteria - add that to your query then put the query into a cursor and do an OPEN...FETCH INTO ... CLOSE to grab that row first and populate your variable. You won't need your EXCEPTION block doing it this way, you instead after the fetch do IF cursorname%NOTFOUND THEN dbms_output() ENDIF;

```
declare
  cursor get_migrationidentifier (in_lat_decimal number, in_long_decimal number)
  IS
         select migrationidentifier  from 
         (select com.migrationidentifier
           ,row_number () over (partition by com.migrationidentifier order by com.migrationidentifier asc) RK
           from com_location com
          where round (i.latitude_a_decimal, 1) =
                   round (com.LATITUDEWGS84, 1)
                and round (i.longitude_a_decimal, 1) =
                       round (com.longitudewgs84, 1)
                and com.sourcedomain = 'FENIX') where rk=1
              order by migrationidentifier  ;
begin 
  for i in c1
   loop 
   if i.estacao_a2 is not null then
      OPEN get_migrationidentifier (i.latitude_a_decimal. i.longitude_a_decimal); 
      FETCH get_migrationidentifier  INTO v_master_location;
      IF get_migrationidentifier%NOTFOUND 
      THEN  v_master_location := null;
            dbms_output.
            put_line (
               'NO RECORDS FOUND IN COM_LOCATION FOR LATITUDE:'
               || i.latitude_a_decimal);
      end IF;
      CLOSE get_migrationidentifier;

  end if;
   end loop;
```